# Getting error on login with angular 2 google and firebase

Tags: authentication, angular, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am using firebase 3 and ng 2.
My issue I am getting error when click on connect with google account.
My error is:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

    400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: Events Manager

You can email the developer of this application at: .....@gmail.com

The redirect URI in the request, https://......firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/......apps.googleusercontent.com?project=181586 to update the authorized redirect URIs.
```

my project runs on http://localhost:3000/#/login

when I am going to  console.developers.google.com  Authorized redirect URIs-> http://localhost:3000/

Any idea whey is it happens?

Comment: Hey Vitaly, you have to whitelist the url https://<projectId>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler in your google oauth client.

Comment: Authorized JavaScript origins->Origin URIs must not contain a path or end with "/":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was need to add to firebase auth link the correct host.

firebase-> OAuth redirect domains